# ViewPager and ImageGallery

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

The problem is this:

When you first choose a picture - everything is fine. If you swipe, and press the "back" button, after you open another image then will open last image which will opened.

The correct position is passed through the Bundle. I don’t understand where to look for the error.

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_fScreen);
        Hit hit = hits.get(position);

        Picasso.get().load(hit.getLargeImageURL())
                .into(imageView);

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return hits.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

DialogFragment:

```
public class FullScreenDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
private ArrayList<Hit> hits;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
private TextView author;
private TextView count;
private int selectedPosition;
private Button buttonShare;
private static FullScreenDialogFragment fullScreenDialogFragment;
private int rlyPosition;

public static FullScreenDialogFragment getInstance() {
    if (fullScreenDialogFragment == null) {
        fullScreenDialogFragment = new FullScreenDialogFragment();
    }
    return fullScreenDialogFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.DialogStyle);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_viewpager, container, false);
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    author = view.findViewById(R.id.author);
    buttonShare = view.findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
    count = view.findViewById(R.id.count);
    hits = (ArrayList<Hit>) getArguments().getSerializable("hits");
    selectedPosition = getArguments().getInt("position");

    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(onViewPageChangeListener);

   

    setItem(selectedPosition);
    return view;
}

private void setItem(int pos) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos, true);
    setItemInfo(selectedPosition);

}

private void setItemInfo(int pos) {
    count.setText((pos + 1) + " of " + hits.size());

    Hit hit = hits.get(pos);
    author.setText(hit.getUser());



}


ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onViewPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        setItemInfo(position);



    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I Guess the Problem is here

```
private void setItem(int pos) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos, true);
    setItemInfo(selectedPosition);

}
```

You might be passing the selectedPosition instead of currentPosition

Please check.

Comment: selectedPosition i'm getting from recycler clicklistener, problem is not here :(

Comment: Yes, try to pass pos into setItemInfo()

Comment: I'm try it, nope :(

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in creating DialogFramgent object.
I did it him in Singlton pattern and called it with old data.

Now in OnClick i'm created new object DialogFramget and him get new values.

```
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fullScreenDialog = new FullScreenDialogFragment();
            fullScreenDialog.setArguments(bundle);
            fullScreenDialog.show(fragmentTransaction, "");
```